# Attempted import error: 'showErrorMessage' is not exported from '../helpers/alerts'

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a file named alerts.js in the folder ../helpers/alerts

```
const showSuccessMessage = (success) => {
    <div className="alert alert-success">{success}</div>
}
const showErrorMessage = (error) => {
    <div className="alert alert-success">{error}</div>
}

module.exports ={
    showErrorMessage, showSuccessMessage
}
```

I try to import those both functions in another file

```
import {showSuccessMessage, showErrorMessage} from '../helpers/alerts'
```

But I keep receiving

> Attempted import error: 'showErrorMessage' is not exported from
> '../helpers/alerts'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the code below.

```
export const showSuccessMessage = (success) => {
    <div className="alert alert-success">{success}</div>
}
export const showErrorMessage = (error) => {
    <div className="alert alert-success">{error}</div>
}
```

```
import {showSuccessMessage, showErrorMessage} from '../helpers/alerts'
```

Comment: This works, but its weird. I thought module.exports was basically the same. Could you explain why that happens?